# Problems w/ themes and multi-site installation

Tags: theming, multi-sites, 7

so i'm currently migrating a single install drupal site into a multi-site drupal install, and for some reason it doesn't seem to be picking up my templates... which is a bit odd considerign that when in the drupal admin interface on the actual client facing CMS I can see that i'm in the correct "theme" which is a custom theme called "press".

however, drupal isn't using my page.tpl.php file. So what I did was hit the main drupal install and opened up bootstrap.inc and found that it is finding the correct directory for the conf and everything... not sure what else to do.

something that's interesting is that if I ping my site on localhost it looks as though it's pulling in 1 block (which should be displayed on the homepage), no wrapper, no menus, etc (which is why i think it's not using the correct templates, also the html is formatted differently than when it uses the correct template).

this is what i did to migrate

1. moved moved settings.php/modules/themes/files into the drupal/sites/mysite
2. reconfig'd my httpd.conf to point to the right site (it is).
3. reset my file path from sites/default/files to drupal/sites/mysite/files

using - drupal 7

curious if anyone has any advice or knows how I can investigate this further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also experienced this issue as well. It seems that drupal doesn't want to recognise themes and modules on a multisite subdomain basis (i.e. sites/yoursite.com/themes is ignored!!!). I don't know if this is intended behaviour but the only solution I have found thus far is to put all modules and themes into the sites/all folder and then to check they are enabled in the admin interface.
Drupal will correctly respond to the subdomain request (and rewrite paths where appropriate) so long as you have the sites/yoursite.com folder.

Answer (score 2):

This problem resolved itself for me when I moved my sites/default/settings.php file to sites/mysite.com/settings.php.